# How can I add an List with different data after loop beside existing list?

Tags: c#, list, linq

so bassicly I've got 2 different List

```
  List<string> result = new List<string>;
  List<string> outputs= new List<string>;
```

the outputs List getting filled in an loop and after the loop ends it will add the `outputs` list in the `result` list.

So that outputs will have this different values after the loop ends.

For example after the first loop ends the `output` list has data like:

```
exampleData1
exampleData2
exampleData3
```

and so on

so that the `result` List would now have this three example data.

Now the loop will hit again and will load different data like:

```
exampleData1.1
exampleData2.1
exampleData3.1
```

and now It should add this three example data to the `result` list:

so that now the result list should look like that:

```
exampleData1, exampleData1.1
exampleData2, exampleData2.1
exampleData3, exampleData3.1
```

and so should It go on after each `loop` after the `output` list changed it should be add side by side like one string.

I have tried things like that:

```
foreach (var (item1, item2) in output.Zip(output, (xo, y) => (xo, y)))
    result.Add($" {item1}, {item2}");
```

but that's only adding the existing list side by side so that I have 2x the same value side by side.

I hope I have explained it understandable and if not, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zip` is good idea, but care. From the documentation :

> If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them.

As `result` is empty, the end is reached before to start. The solution is to complete with the elements not iterated by `Zip` :

```cs
result = result.Zip(outputs, (r, o) => r + ", " + o)
    .Union(result.Skip(outputs.Count)) // Add element from result not iterated by Zip
    .Union(outputs.Skip(result.Count)) // Add element from outputs not iterated by Zip
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thats exatly what Ive been searching for, thank you very much for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0 I think you have a mistake in your code. You're "zipping" `outputs` with `outputs` (i.e. itself) you need to zip it with `result`.

```
var mergedLists = result.Zip(outputs, (first, second) => first + " " + second);
```

**UPDATED**
Here's a full console app solution:

```
List<string> result = new();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    List<string> outputs = new();
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        outputs.Add($"TestData{i}.{j}");
    }

    if (!result.Any())
    {
        result = outputs.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        result = result.Zip(outputs, (first, second) => first + " " + second).ToList();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I need to make it in the result list not in var mergedLists which is from Type not an normal List<string>

Comment: and if result is empty after the first loop then the zip function dont seem to work and result stays empty

Comment: I've updated my answer ^^